# MDX: Loop through variable and populate table

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

Is it possible to loop through several variables in MDX? I want to filter my query based on 3 conditions, each of which consists 2 * 2 * 3 variables. I was looking for a better way than changing the WHERE clause 12 times to make 12 tables and finally append together.

This is how I imagine it would look like:

```
Market  2015 2016 2017 Condition1 Condition2 Condition3
Market 1 $$   $$   $$      ABC      Direct       B2B
Market 1 $$   $$   $$      ABC      Direct       B2C
Market 1 $$   $$   $$      ABC      Direct       Other
Market 1 $$   $$   $$      ABC      Trade        B2B
Market 1 $$   $$   $$      ABC      Trade        B2C
Market 1 $$   $$   $$      ABC      Trade        Other
Market 1 $$   $$   $$      DEF      Direct       B2B
Market 1 $$   $$   $$      DEF      Direct       B2C
Market 1 $$   $$   $$      DEF      Direct       Other
Market 1 $$   $$   $$      DEF      Trade        B2B
Market 1 $$   $$   $$      DEF      Trade        B2C
Market 1 $$   $$   $$      DEF      Trade        Other
       ...
```

EDIT: Here is my query (probably not optimal since I am a total noob in MDX):

```
WITH
SET [Market1] AS (
    [Market].[Market].[Market].&[103],
    EXCEPT({[Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].ALLMEMBERS}, 
        {[Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[111],
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[116],
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[242],
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[134]}
    ))


SET [Market2] AS (
    [Market].[Market].[Market].&[106],
    EXCEPT({[Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].ALLMEMBERS}, 
        {[Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[192],
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[157]}
    ))


SET [Market3] AS {(
    [Market].[Market].[Market].&[102],
    EXCEPT({[Source Currency].[Source Currency Code].[All].children}, 
        {[Source Currency].[Source Currency Code].[EUR], 
        [Source Currency].[Source Currency Code].[USD]}),
    EXCEPT({[Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].ALLMEMBERS}, 
        {[Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[112],
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[309]})
    ),
    (
    [Market].[Market].[Market].&[102],
    [Source Currency].[Source Currency Code].[EUR],
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[186]
    )} 


SET [Market4] AS {
    ([Market].[Market].[Market].&[105],
    [Source Currency].[Source Currency Code].[All]), 
    ([Market].[Market].[Market].&[102],
    [Source Currency].[Source Currency Code].[USD])}

SET [Market5] AS {(
    [Market].[Market].[Market].&[102],
    [Source Currency].[Source Currency Code].[EUR],
    EXCEPT({[Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].ALLMEMBERS}, 
        {[Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[112],
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[186],
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[139],
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[180],
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[188],
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[234],
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[269],
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[291],
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[185],
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[195],
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[203],
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[253],
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[283],
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[243] 
        })),
    (
    [Market].[Market].[Market].&[102],
    [Source Currency].[Source Currency Code].[GBP],
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[309]
    ),
    (
    [Market].[Market].[Market].&[103],
    [Source Currency].[Source Currency Code].[All],
    {[Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[111],
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[116],
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[242],
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[134]}
    ),
    (
    [Market].[Market].[Market].&[106],
    [Source Currency].[Source Currency Code].[All],
    {[Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[192],
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[157]}
    )}

SET [Market6] AS {(
    [Market].[Market].[Market].&[102],
    [Source Currency].[Source Currency Code].[All],
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[112]
    ), 
    ([Market].[Market].[Market].&[102],
    [Source Currency].[Source Currency Code].[EUR],
    {[Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[139],
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[180],
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[188],
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[234],
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[269],
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[291],
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[185],
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[195],
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[203],
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[253],
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[283],
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[243]
    })}

SET [Market7] AS (
    [Market].[Market].[Market].&[104],
    EXCEPT({[Agency].[Market - Agency].[Agency].ALLMEMBERS}, 
        {[Agency].[Market - Agency].[Agency].&[155861]}
    ))

SET [Market8] AS (
    [Market].[Market].[Market].&[104],
    [Agency].[Market - Agency].[Agency].&[155861]
)

SET [YTD2015] AS (
[Departure Date].[Year].&[2015],
StrToMember("[Report Date].[Report Date].&[" + Str(Int(CDbl(Now()) - 38718 - 731)) + "]")
)

SET [YTD2016] AS (
[Departure Date].[Year].&[2016],
StrToMember("[Report Date].[Report Date].&[" + Str(Int(CDbl(Now()) - 38718 - 365)) + "]")
)

SET [YTD2017] AS (
[Departure Date].[Year].&[2017],
StrToMember("[Report Date].[Report Date].&[" + Str(Int(CDbl(Now()) - 38718)) + "]")
)

MEMBER [Market].[Market].[Market1] AS
SUM([Market1], [Measures].[Price])

MEMBER [Market].[Market].[Market2] AS
SUM([Market2], [Measures].[Price])

MEMBER [Market].[Market].[Market3] AS
SUM([Market3], [Measures].[Price])

MEMBER [Market].[Market].[Market4] AS
SUM([Market4], [Measures].[Price])

MEMBER [Market].[Market].[Market5] AS
SUM([Market5], [Measures].[Price])

MEMBER [Market].[Market].[Market6] AS
SUM([Market6], [Measures].[Price])

MEMBER [Market].[Market].[Market7] AS
SUM([Market7], [Measures].[Price])

MEMBER [Market].[Market].[Market8] AS
SUM([Market8], [Measures].[Price])

MEMBER [Market].[Market].[Grand Total] AS 
SUM([Market].[Market].[All], [Measures].[Price])

SELECT {[YTD2015], [YTD2016],
        [YTD2017]} ON COLUMNS,
    {[Market].[Market].[Market1], [Market].[Market].[Market2],
    [Market].[Market].[Market3], [Market].[Market].[Market4],
    [Market].[Market].[Market5], [Market].[Market].[Market6],
    [Market].[Market].[Market7], [Market].[Market].[Market8],
    [Market].[Market].[Grand Total]} ON ROWS
FROM [Booking]
WHERE ({ [Travel Type].[Travel Type].&[101],
        [Travel Type].[Travel Type].&[102],
        [Travel Type].[Travel Type].&[103] })
```

So now I get the total YTD sum for each market for the three years. Now I want to split this total up further in the groups that I mentioned above.

Comment: When you say "filter my query" do you mean you want to see less rows in your results set, or do you want the numbers to reduce (same rows)?

Comment: Hi, I have already got it down to 8 rows (which is the sum for each market and for each year - 2015, 2016 and 2017), but now I want to "drill" it down further, so to speak, by adding those conditions as I stated in the post. So far the only thing I can think of is to add a WHERE Condition1=ABC, Condition2=Direct, Condition3=B2B, and to repeat this for all the conditions and append every table together when I'm done, but this seems way to tedious, so I thought it must be a better way. So basically I want more rows, to see where the income is distributed across the different conditions

Comment: I think I need to see the MDX you've tried, and then I might be able to advise. (But I might not!)

Comment: Thanks, please see my edit where I have attached the query

Comment: I'm sorry. I've looked at the query for a long time, and I cannot really comprehend what you need to do to change it. I think you need to think of other ways to achieve this. Perhaps you can create another dimension on the cube? This might be more powerful, and easier to understand.

Comment: Yes, as I've said, the only thing that I can imagine is to use a WHERE clause with all those different conditions, but that would be wildly inefficient, so the best thing is to probably change the query as a whole, but I don't really have much experience in this. Unfortunately I can't change anything in the cube since I don't have any administrator privileges, so I'm kind of constrained. But thanks for reaching out!

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about it from a wrong angle, I solved it using cross-joins (which I'd never heard about before).

Here is a good article about cross-joins:
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_3334631_3/MDX-Essentials-Basic-Set-Functions-The-CrossJoin-Function.htm